# Grape Swagger UI - Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'definitions' of null

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, swagger, swagger-ui, ruby-grape, grape-api

So I came to this error when using Swagger UI and trying to hit the API.

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'definitions' of null
```

I'm using the gem `grape-swagger` and the UI says is trying to retrieve the records.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue was, another member of the team had commented the line

```
add_swagger_documentation api_version: 'v1', mount_path: '/docs'
```

that must be placed in the class **AFTER** all the mounted APIs

```
class Root < Grape::API
  blah blah blah...
  mount BLAH::BLAH
  mount FOO::BAR
  add_swagger_documentation api_version: 'v1', mount_path: '/docs'
end
```

After putting it there again it worked!

Answer (score 1):

**Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'definitions' of null**

swagger integration was done and I received above error. Because I was missing @Api annotation on rest service and I was trying to run. Hope this might be one reason that you will receive this error

Comment: I am getting the same error. But I can't understand how you resolved it. You were missing @Api annotation ? What you mean by this?

Answer (score 0):

Hope this may help someone who finds this question here. I also got the same error. But the reason is different. Here the reason was I added the 'add_swagger_documentation' method above the mounting of all apis.

Here I am using [grape-swagger-rails](https://github.com/ruby-grape/grape-swagger-rails) gem with Grape in Rails 4.2

**We have to add the method 'add_swagger_documentation' after mounting the all grape apis.**

Check the following github conversation

https://github.com/ruby-grape/grape-swagger-rails/issues/58